# Transpose Function in R is not transposing

Tags: r, vector, transpose

Trying to transpose a vector in R and then name it.

I created a vector, `v` as follows:

```
v<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

But when I try to transpose as:

```
t(v)
```

It gives the output:

```
t(v)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]

[1,]    1    2    3    4
```

I know I can create a matrix or define a vector the other way, but I think the bigger issue is why transpose itself is not working. I do not have any packages installed or things like that.

Comment: What is your expected output\

Comment: The transpose column vector with four rows

Comment: `matrix(v1)` would get you that

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question as to why t(v) is not working. Shouldn't it work or can you only add in matrix to get the transpose? I feel like that should not be the case.

Comment: a transpose of a vector is a row vector, what you need is already what you have. a vector is considered to be a column vector. which might be loosly translated as a matrix with one column..

Comment: Oh right stupid. This is why the output of having it on 1 line is annoying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Create data
v<-c(1,2,3,4)

#In addition to the answers presented prior to mine, you could do this. 
t(t(v))
    [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. I submitted without realizing an answer was already posted. You're fast.

Comment: No problem.  It is not the answer OP wanted though\