# Transpose a vector into a single column?

Tags: r

Can't believe I have never noticed that before in R!

If I transpose a vector, it does not give a single-column matrix like I would expect.

**Example**

```
test <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

t(test)
```

> [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
>   [1,] 1    2    3    4

And that is creating a problem in one of my functions.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Also, read about `drop = FALSE`. Maybe you are losing dimensions of the matrix in your function when subsetting, something like: `mymat <- data[ , 1]`, this way we are dropping dims, instead try to use `mymat <- data[ , 1, drop = FALSE]`. Then maybe there will be no need to transpose anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We wrap with `matrix` and by default it gives a single column

```
matrix(test)
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
#[4,]    4
```

as the documentation of `?matrix` says

> If one of nrow or ncol is not given, an attempt is made to infer it from the length of data and the other parameter. If neither is given, a one-column matrix is returned.

---

Also, `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes, So, another option is assignment of `dim` attributes

```
dim(test) <- c(length(test), 1)
```

---

The reason why `t`ranspose does this is according to `?t`

> When x is a vector, it is treated as a column, i.e., the result is a 1-row matrix.

Comment: That's great! I should have precised a bit my question: what approach would you use if I do not know if `test` is going to be a single-row vector or a multi-row matrix? Any method that would flip both? I could always test if it is a single-row vector, but there may be better a better solution...

Comment: @francoiskroll. You can have an `if/else` with `is.vector`

Comment: Okay, no generic way then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @francoiskroll. Or otherwise, convert to a vector and apply only a single function i.e. `as.vector(objectName)`.  In that case, you would be sure that it would always be a `vector`

Comment: You may want to add `t(t(test))` in your answer to be comprehensive about the different options (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201856/transpose-function-in-r-is-not-transposing). Weird notation but it works...

Comment: @francoiskroll. I think that is in the dupe tagged one.  It would be inefficient for large vector as we are doing double transpose