# How to transpose a row to a column array in R?

Tags: r, transpose

I have an array like the following:

```
v <- 1:100
```

It is a row array. I would like to transpose it to a column array, like e.g.

```
1
2
3
...
```

(and so on). I tried with

```
t(v)
```

but I did not obtain the desired result:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
     [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39]
[1,]    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39
     [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58]
[1,]    40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58
     [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77]
[1,]    59    60    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77
     [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96]
[1,]    78    79    80    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90    91    92    93    94    95    96
     [,97] [,98] [,99] [,100]
[1,]    97    98    99    100
```

Comment: `t(t(v))`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201856/transpose-function-in-r-is-not-transposing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose Function in R is not transposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201856/transpose-function-in-r-is-not-transposing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a matrix `as.matrix(v)`. Though curious as to why you need this format?